# Why unable to access variable of setter function into getter function in same contract

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I want to access this, winner.transfer(getMoney()) in function showWinner(). This lottery contract in selectWinner(), we can get our winner and in showWinner(), I want to display or print that winner but showWinner() function gave an error.

```
contract Lottery{
    address public manager;
    address payable[] public participants; 

    constructor(){
        manager = msg.sender;   
    }

    receive() external payable{       
        require(msg.value == 1 ether);
        participants.push(payable(msg.sender));
    } 

    function getMoney() public view returns(uint){
        require(msg.sender == manager);
        return address(this).balance;
    }

    function random() public view returns(uint){
        return uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.difficulty,block.timestamp,participants.length)));
    }
   ////// see below code ////////

    function selectWinner() public{
        require(msg.sender == manager);
        require(participants.length >= 3);
        uint r = random();
        address payable winner;
        uint index = r % participants.length;   
        winner = participants[index];
        winner.transfer(getMoney());   
    }

    function showWinner() public view returns(address){
         return winner.transfer(getMoney());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`winner` is defined locally within your `selectWinner()` function, So you can't access it in your `showWinner()` unless you declare it globally on top of your contract :

```
address payable public winner;
function selectWinner() public {
 /* Codes */
}
...
```

Also, using `transfer` which is a state-changing method, can't be placed within a `view` function and `transfer` method does not return 'address' type, so `showWinner()` function should return `bool`,

```
function showWinner() public returns(bool) {
      return winner.transfer(getMoney());
}
```

---

** Update :

```
contract Lottery{
    address public manager;
    address payable[] public participants; 
    address payable selectedWinner;

    constructor(){
        manager = msg.sender;   
    }

    receive() external payable{       
        require(msg.value == 1 ether);
        participants.push(payable(msg.sender));
    } 

    function getMoney() public view returns(uint){
        require(msg.sender == manager);
        return address(this).balance;
    }

    function random() public view returns(uint){
        return uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.difficulty,block.timestamp,participants.length)));
    }
   
    function selectWinner() public{
        require(msg.sender == manager);
        require(participants.length >= 3);
        uint r = random();

        /* No need a local declaration, so comment out below */
        /* address payable winner; */

        uint index = r % participants.length;

        /* Instead, assign winner to the global variable */
        selectedWinner = participants[index];
        selectedWinner.transfer(getMoney());   
    }

    function showWinner() public view returns(address){
         return selectedWinner;
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to print winner name in showWinner( ) method, with bool how can print ? @RohanDara

Comment: Post is updated as per your full example.

Comment: Note that, block difficulty and block timestamp are not a good source for Random Number Generation.